# Angular UiRouter potentially infinitely nested states.... Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Ok so here's my problem Imagine a photo feed that can be grouped by tags.

I have states feed, feed.photo and feed.photo.tags;

Now when you go to feed.photo.tags its meant to show you all tags that you tagged the photo with.

But from there I'd like to be able to click the tag and see the feed of photos grouped by this tag so dynamically go to feed.photo.tags.feed and from there deeper and deeper as much as linking allows me (feed.photo.tags.feed.photo.tags.feed.photo.tags....) potentially infinitely nested.

Can someone point me in the right direction whether it is possible to do without actually specifying the state nesting through the $stateProvider other than getting to lets say feed.photo.tags and from there going dynamically down whatever route user chooses?

Also its not just a combination of feed.photo.tags it could be for example feed.photo.userprofile.feed.photo.tags.feed.photo.comments.userprofile etc... its not a finite list it could literally take you anywhere in the app. It kinda would have to generate possible child states at the moment of loading certain state.

Comment: Why don't you redirect to "feed" ?

Comment: Going into feed.photo.tags.feed mean a part of the feed.photo.tags will be updated. And i guess you don't have a nested view to show a feed into a feed.photo.tags view.

Comment: use wildcards in url definitions

Comment: @Okazari ok feed.photo.tags.feed is going to be different to the feed using the same directive but the content would be completely different as the photo you viewed would be just one of many in that tag so navigating back to feed would not achieve the result I am after.

Comment: @charlietfl what kind of wildcards? the url generated this way coul potentially be infinite. I am making a counterpart to the iOS app which uses  navigation stack for that. Potentially this will probably have a massive impact on performance I am assuming unless I am using the same container over and over again and recursively navigate and append to the base state. is that even possible?

Comment: @VicJ Ok for the first one. But you should fix a limit. Even visually. I feel like you can provide maybe two nested feed (i mean feed to feed circle) MAX then you will need to force to go back to "feed" for that tag. At least it's my opinion. Could you maybe add a drawing to illustrate the final view you're after ?